# upgrade weblogic server from 12cr1 to 12cr2

Tags: weblogic12c

I need to know how can i upgrade my Weblogic application server from release 1 to release 2.
My OS is windows 7 64 bit. I am new to this some one else installed weblogic so i tried to install it by myself but it is giving me error

C:\Users\User\Downloads>java -D64 -jar wls_121200.jar
Extracting files................................................................
....................................
This installer must be executed using a Java Development Kit (JDK)
but C:\Program Files\Java\jre7 is not a valid JDK.
The Oracle Universal Installer failed.  Exiting.

so i unzipped the jar with 7 zip now intaller has started is it the correct way?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using command prompt, navigate to the directory where you downloaded the installation program.

Launch the installation program by invoking `java -jar` from the JDK directory on your system,

as shown in the example below:

`\home\Oracle\jdk7_15\jdk1.7.0_15\bin\java -jar wls_121200.jar` -- sure to replace `\home\Oracle\jdk7_15\jdk1.7.0_15` -- in this example with the location of the JDK on your system

Answer (score 4):

The only thing you need is to *execute the installer using the jdk* needed for it.
for example:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe" -jar wls_121200.jar
```

I used the `java.exe` from my jdk 7 folder instead of the java installed on my computer.

The *weblogic* jar folder doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

use the following command:

> C:\Softwares\Weblogic12c> "\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\bin"\java
>   -jar fmw_12.2.1.0.0_wls.jar

**C:\Softwares\Weblogic12c>** is the location of my weblogic jar file.

"\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\bin"\ is the location of my jdk.

Answer (score 0):

It may happen that the jar is not taking the JAVA_HOME or PATH variables that may be set in the environment variables. In this case you may set it manually in the cmd. GOTO Run->cmd.
Then goto the folder where you have placed your jar

`C:\Users\User\Downloads>set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\...\jdk1.8.0_112`

`C:\Users\User\Downloads>set PATH=C:\Program Files\...\jdk1.8.0_112\bin;%PATH%`
and then you may go on executing the jar,

`C:\Users\User\Downloads>java -jar wls_121200.jar`

It worked for me! Hope it helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. **Run as Administrator** the Command Prompt
2. Open the Weblogic's jar directory
3. Execute the java -jar command over the jar file:

   **From Runtime Variable *(Make sure you have it set)***

   ```
   java -jar wls_121200.jar
   ```

   **From sepecific directory**

   ```
   "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe" -jar wls_121200.jar
   ```